# setting google push notifications result to error 401 Unauthorized WebHook callback channel

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, push-notification, google-api, drive

I am trying to use the drive API with push notifications that let me watch for changes to my file.

i follow the guide form google.

my steps :

*Step 1: Verify that you own the domain* **done**

[google search console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPV2K.png)

*Step 2: Register your domain* **done** (i tried with multiple URL)

[google domain verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6NN9.png)

*Creating notification channels*

this is a simple node server for the webhook that i have deploy on the google app engine.

```
/* jshint node: true */
'use strict';

const key = require('./SBSWideDomainDev.json');
const google = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');
var path = require("path");
const logging = require('./logging');

const app = express();

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.post('/notification', (req, res, next) => {
    logging.info(res.body);
    res.status(200).json(res.body);
});

if (module === require.main) {
    var test = 8080;
    const server = app.listen(test, () => {
        const port = server.address().port;
        console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
    });
}
```

and i use live demo on the google page for file.watch

```
fileId : "some FileId",
request body:
{
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://notif-dot-sullivan-business-solution-dev.appspot.com/notification",
  "id": "e64d0c44-f9a2-4db8-8d21-94ee0904dcb7"
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://notif-dot-sullivan-business-solution-dev.appspot.com/notification"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://notif-dot-sullivan-business-solution-dev.appspot.com/notification"
 }
}
```

I absolutely don't have an idea where the problem is, i had follow the google guide exactly. And it's been three days i'm working on it.

(sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong - but I have used Goolge Drive API and to be able to successfully make request I had to generate OAuth token for my registered application. Have you registered one ? If not see here how to authenticate your application, google provides different ways to do it https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth.

After obtaining a token you should add it to your request as header property.

'Authorization': 'Bearer '.

Also keep in mind that google Oauth tokens expire in 1 hour after their generation and you should regenerate it.

Comment: i use the live demo for the drive.file.watch (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/watch) that automaticly provide me an OAuth token for the request.